# Exception: Cannot assign two Admin() instances with same URL and subdomain to the same application

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin, flask-security

I am trying to restrict access to admin panel using flask-admin but i am getting error. I have also tried changing url name but then it throws **404** error. When using flask-admin with ModelView getting the following error:

> Exception: Cannot assign two Admin() instances with same URL and subdomain to the same application.

**app/__init__.py** :

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_mail import Mail
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler, RotatingFileHandler
import os
from flask_admin import Admin, BaseView, expose
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView


app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'templates/static/'
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
mail = Mail(app)
admin = Admin(app)


if not app.debug:
    if app.config['MAIL_SERVER']:
        auth = None
        if app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] or app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']:
            auth = (app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'], app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'])
        secure = None
        if app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']:
            secure = ()
        mail_handler = SMTPHandler(
            mailhost=(app.config['MAIL_SERVER'], app.config['MAIL_PORT']),
            fromaddr='no-reply@' + app.config['MAIL_SERVER'],
            toaddrs=app.config['ADMINS'], subject='Bhavtaal Failure',
            credentials=auth, secure=secure)
        mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)

    if not os.path.exists('logs'):
        os.mkdir('logs')
    file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/bhavtaal.log', maxBytes=10240,
                                       backupCount=10)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.info('Bhavtaal startup')


from app import routes, models, errors
from app.models import User
from app.admin import AdminView

admin = Admin(app, name='Home', index_view=AdminView(User, db.session, url='/admin', endpoint='users_'))
```

**app/admin.py** :

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask import session, redirect, url_for, request


class AdminView(ModelView):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.static_folder = 'templates/static/'

    def is_accessible(self):
        return session.get('user') == 'admin'

    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_accessible():
            return redirect(url_for('index.html', next=request.url))
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to solve this after removing this line:

> admin = Admin(app)

Please follow this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYWEf9bZhHQ). It has all the information.